# Set an image between coordinates

Tags: android

Here is an example of what I need to do:

First of all I convert the image into bitmap and then set it as background to a relative layout. And i know these four coordinates.

Then how can I get the image inside the box and set it to another layout as background?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not the place where someone will code for you, but answer questions and help you with specifc problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Picasso when you are dealing with Images.

[This is the link](http://square.github.io/picasso/)